# compile the Espresso project : make[1]: lint: Command not found

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cmake, makefile, lint

I'm compiling the "Espresso" project in Ubuntu download from here(https://ptolemy.berkeley.edu/projects/embedded/pubs/downloads/espresso/index.htm).When I type command "make" under the project, there is an error: `make[1]: lint: Command not found`. So I checked the Makefile file, I found a line code

```
lint: ${LSRC} ${DRVRSRC} ${HDR} ${LINTLIBS}
     lint ${LINTFLAGS} ${LSRC} ${DRVRSRC} ${LINTLIBS} ${LDFLAGS} | tee lint
```

I guess the "lint" maybe a Linux command, and I should install it by hand. So I search online and try to use `apt-get install splint` from someone's advice to solve this problem, but it doesn't work. I need help...

Comment: There's no `lint` on Ubuntu, but [this answer on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/753640/2639) might help you.

Comment: Also, define *but it doesn't work*. You installed `splint`, but did you updated the `Makefile` to `splint` instead of `lint`?

Comment: Note that Expresso (at that download site) has not been updated in ~28 years.  It is not surprising that the Makefile needs some tweaks to get it to build on a **modern** Ubuntu machine.